# how to avoid same line adding multiple times in c#

Tags: c#

I have a condition that program reads lines from a file 'assign.txt' and then gets data from last 6 underscores and then writes that data to another file `line.txt`.

But before writing data to `line.txt` I have to check whether the data already exists in `line.txt` if yes then skip or replace the existing data but each data in `line.txt` should be unique the file `assign.txt` can contain multiple lines

```
foreach (string fileLine in File.ReadAllLines("F:\\assign.txt"))
{
    string tel_in = "TELENOR_BTS_INCOMING";

    string telenor = fileLine.ToUpper();

    var delimeter = "_";
    if (telenor.Contains(tel_in))
    {
        var lineParts = fileLine.Split(new[] { delimeter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (lineParts.Length > 1) lineParts = lineParts.Skip(1).ToArray();
        var data = string.Join(delimeter, lineParts.Skip(lineParts.Length - 7));

        lineData.Add(data);

        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", lineData);
    }
    else
    {
        var lineParts = fileLine.Split(new[] { delimeter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        if (lineParts.Length > 1) lineParts = lineParts.Skip(1).ToArray();
        var data = string.Join(delimeter, lineParts.Skip(lineParts.Length - 6));

        lineData.Add(data);

        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Adnan Haider\Desktop\line.txt", lineData);
    }   
}
```

**this is line.txt sample output file**

> Mobilink_User_dpo_bahawalpur_0506768768685465367658717_1205‌​42.out
>   Telenor_bts_outgoing_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
>   Telenor_bts_outgoing_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
>   Telenor_bts_incoming_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
>   Telenor_bts_incoming_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
>   Ufone_User_dpo_chakwal_030617_15235869694.out

**this is assign.txt sample**

> dpo.chakwal63201732033PM_FL_Telenor_bts_outgoing_dpo_chakwal‌​_030617_15201696981.‌​out
>   dpo.chakwal63201732033PM_FL_Telenor_bts_outgoing_dpo_chakwal‌​_030617_15201696981.‌​out

upper lines are output samples `line.txt` samples and lower lines are input lines `assign.txt` i want to write output in `line.txt` but first i have to check if the data already existed in `line.txt` if yes then skip or replace output with that existing line else write data to `line.txt`

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input?  It's not entirely clear from your description or your posted code what you're trying to do.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? And can you give some examples of the `assign.txt` and `line.txt` so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Tim Lol same answer

Comment: @JordyvanEijk - yep :)

Comment: Why don't you first read "line.txt" into a List or Dictionary. Then run through "assign.txt" checking, if  the item is in List or Dictionary, and then at the end overwriting the whole "line.txt" with the contents of the amended List (Dictionary).

Comment: You can use HashSet for performance while checking for uniqueness

Comment: @tim //  this is line.txt sample output file "Mobilink_User_dpo_bahawalpur_0506768768685465367658717_120542.out
Telenor_bts_outgoing_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
Telenor_bts_outgoing_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
Telenor_bts_incoming_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
Telenor_bts_incoming_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
Ufone_User_dpo_chakwal_030617_15235869694.out

// this is assign.txt sample

dpo.chakwal63201732033PM_FL_Telenor_bts_outgoing_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out
dpo.chakwal63201732033PM_FL_Telenor_bts_outgoing_dpo_chakwal_030617_15201696981.out

Comment: upper lines are output samples `line.txt` samples 
and lower lines are input lines `assign.txt`
 i want to write output in `line.txt` but first i have to check if the data already existed in `line.txt` if yes then skip or replace output with that existing line else write data to `line.txt`

Answer (score -1):

There are different approaches to [Loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_loops.htm).  This is the one I would suggest.  No Try/Catch nor using() {}, but you get the idea.

```
string[] m_fileLine = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\\assign.txt");
StreamWriter m_results = new StreamWriter(@"F:\\results.txt", true);

string tel_in = "TELENOR_BTS_INCOMING";

for (int i = 0; i < m_fileLine.Length; i++)
{
  if (m_fileLine[i].ToUpper().Contains(tel_in))
  {
  // some logic here...
  // then write here...
    m_results.WriteLine(m_fileLine[i].ToString());
    m_results.Flush();
  }
  else
  {
    // else logic and write here...
  }

}
```